is it dangerous to leave DS_store files left in git commit history?
I forgot to add it to my gitignore and although I've added .DS_Store to my gitignore now, I was wondering if it was dangerous to leave for anyone to see in my git commit history.
edit: I'm clearly not asking if .DS_store files should be in my repo or not. I'm asking if I should remove them from my PREVIOUS commits, because if you go to my commit history, you can access this file. It's already been removed from my current commit.

Does this answer your question? Is .DS_Store file important?

I mean, I suppose it does mostly, but I have also read many posts saying it's dangerous to expose and idk if it'd be dangerous to leave in commit history so

What you keep in the project is what you need in the project. Are the files needed there? If they are not needed, then they should be gone.

yeah I'm not asking if I should keep the files in there or not, I'm asking if I need to make 200 different commits to amend the fact that I had the DS_store files in there for previous commits

how about removing them in a single commit (find . -name .DS_Store -exec git rm {} + && git commit -m "Drop .DS_Store files"), rather than 200 different ones? (and then create a .gitignore file to prevent accidentally adding them again)

Is that command different from find . -name .DS_Store -print0 | xargs -0 git rm -f --ignore-unmatch ? I didn't know you could amend it in one line, thanks!

@umläute To be clear, I think the OP is talking re-writing the repo's history so that the .DS_Store file(s) never existed in the first place. Just deleting the file(s) in a new commit would still leave them in the history. They're asking whether there's anything sensitive enough in that file to justify a history re-write.

@Brian61354270 yes exactly

This is probably better suited for apple.stackexchange.com.

Cross-post to apple.stackexchange.com: Is it dangerous to leave “.DS_Store” files left in Git commit history?
